# Special characters like © and apostrophe not showing in IE and FF

Tags: php, internet-explorer, firefox, character-encoding

i have a php variable

```
$str = "Copyright © 2011 Where I'll Be";
```

in FF (Firefox) and IE (Internet Explorer) it is showing like this

```
Copyright � 2011 Where I�ll Be
```

But in Chrome it is displaying all right.

What PHP built in function I need to apply so that it renders same as my original variable in all browser?

Comment: What character encoding are you specifying in your headers in the in `content-type` meta tag?

Comment: http://www.w3.org/International/techniques/authoring-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The encoding of your php file doesn't match the page encoding of your browser. You can use HTML-Entity encoding, e. g. `&copy;` or fix the file encoding to match that of your browser and server.

Answer (score 1):

When using any special characters you should be using the Html ascii encoding values for them.

There are lots of HTML encoding table on the internet which will help you.

http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Answer (score 1):

http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

this may be useful for you in future